# How to disable other providers (yahoo, aol, hotmail) from facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

I am using facebook comment social plugin to support facebook comment in my site. I am using the following code for that -

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"> </script>
<fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Note that: I'm using no facebook application for commenting.

1. facebook comment box has support to comment using other providers (yahoo,aol and hotmail). But I don't want this. I want to remove this select box. Is it possible to remove that. If possible how?
2. facebook also has an option to subscribe, unsubscribe to any comments. Is it possible to disable or remove that? If possible how?

fb:comments has several options like num_posts, colorscheme, width. Is there any option to disable select box, subscribe/unsubscribe option?

It would be very helpful for me if you guys help me regarding that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Its a facebook bug. Please follow the link below for further details. Thanks.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303593169690073?browse=search_4f3a01ac7cb4f1779248919

Answer (score 0):

```
How I solved this problem....
Case 1) If you login to Facebook then it show you only comment option of facebook...

case 2  But when you log out the it show you comment using (other option like yahoo,aol,hotmail)..
```

**And you don't want these other option in your *Facebook comment* then You need to Do Flowing step**

**STEP ONE .)** Unchecked the following check-box in your **Facebook comment setting popup** [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) of your Application..

**STEP TWO.)** ADD the following Line OF code to your page where you show FACEBOOK comment.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="399031233609403"/>
```

THAT's All ....
**If this is not working for you ....The problem in cache**
change your Dynamic page ......  or open other page  where your Facebook comments
sowing which was not opened YET....
REMEMBER CACHE IS BIG ISSUE ...
I WAS HAVE MANY POST SO I OPENED POST WHICH WAS NOT OPENED YET...ON THAT PAGE MY COMMENT WORKS FINE  :)